# How do I use Boto3 to launch an EC2 instance with an IAM role?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3, amazon-iam

I can not figure out how to launch an EC2 instance in Boto3 with a specified IAM role.

Here is some sampe code of how I have been able to successfully create an instance so far:

```
import boto3
ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2', region_name='us-west-2')
ec2.create_instances(ImageId='ami-1e299d7e', InstanceType='t2.micro',\
MinCount=1, MaxCount=1, SecurityGroupIds=['Mysecuritygroup'], KeyName='mykeyname')
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Note**: Some Boto3 versions accept **either** `Arn` **or** `Name` but all versions accept `Name`. I suggest using the role name only.

```
IamInstanceProfile={
    'Arn': 'string',
    'Name': 'string'
}
```

If your profile name is `ExampleInstanceProfile` and the ARN is `arn:aws:iam::123456789012:instance-profile/ExampleInstanceProfile`

```
ec2.create_instances(ImageId='ami-1e299d7e',
                     InstanceType='t2.micro',
                     MinCount=1, MaxCount=1,
                     SecurityGroupIds=['Mysecuritygroup'],
                     KeyName='mykeyname',
                     IamInstanceProfile={
                            'Arn': 'arn:aws:iam::123456789012:instanceprofile/ExampleInstanceProfile'
                            'Name': 'ExampleInstanceProfile'
                     })
```

Comment: That worked, thank you! Just a note though, it says: 
`The parameter 'iamInstanceProfile.name' may not be used in combination with  'iamInstanceProfile.arn'`

Comment: A few comments here:
1. For the IAM role you want to attach, you will also need to create an [instance profile](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_switch-role-ec2_instance-profiles.html), whose name you will pass in to the command above. If you have created the role through the console, an instance profile will automatically be created for you with the same name as the role.
2. You will need to give the service calling `create_instances` the following iam permissions to add an instance profile - `ec2.AssociateIamInstanceProfile` and `iam.PassRole`.

Answer (score 8):

Just an addition to the great answer by helloV (I can not comment due to reputation limitations).  I encountered the same error message of "The parameter `iamInstanceProfile.name` may not be used in combination with `iamInstanceProfile.arn`.  So only one key is allowed.  I experimented with both and using

```
IamInstanceProfile={ 'Name': 'ExampleInstanceProfile' }
```

works for me, but not using

```
IamInstanceProfile={'Arn':'arn:aws:iam::123456789012:instanceprofile/ExampleInstanceProfile'}
```

I am using boto3 version 1.4.4